# new view for menu for simple ios word game

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm making a simple word game in Objective-C for iOS, and I started out by selecting "Single View Application", so I have one myProgramViewController.xib file, and one each of myProgramViewController.h and myProgramViewController.m. I just now realized that I would like to have a main menu type thing that loads first, and allows the user to select the length of the word, difficulty, stuff like that, and a "Go!" or "Start!" button. How can I add this menu view? I would prefer that the user could not go back to it (for now), so I'd rather not use the navigation bar.

Comment: No I selected the "single view application" when I created it, thinking I would need only one. Is there an easy way to export this existing code to a storyboard format?

Comment: Single View Application can come with a storyboard, its actually a checkbox after that screen. All projects should be made with a storyboard since that's what apple is currently supporting and improving. The answer below should help you though.

Comment: If I were to use storyboards, could I pass through values selected at the main menu view controller to the actual game view controller? Won't they be seperate instances, and therefore not have access to the data from the other?

Comment: Adding an answer since the explanation will be too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can present the view modally. Say you have a view called MainMenu, which has a .xib,.h and .m file.

In your myProgramViewController.m file, you can call the code

```
MainMenu *mainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:mainMenu animated:YES];
```

Then in your MainMenu.m file, once the user has made their selections, call:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Context in comments above.

When a segue happens, you can pass any data from one ViewController to another. What I would do in your case is set up with a storyboard, have the menu controller be the initial view controller, then have the game screen be a modal segue from that. 
In the `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` (on your MenuViewController) you can get segue.destinationViewController and set the data on it.

Example:

```
MenuViewController ---- playGameSegue ----> GameViewController
```

In MenuViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    GameViewController * destination = (GameViewController*) sender.destinationViewController;
    destination.anyPropertyYou'veDefinedInGameViewController.h = DATA;
    destination.otherProperty = DATA;
}
```